# Standard format for biblical quotations

Tags: discussion, formatting

Some people have been using tables to format biblical quotations, such as [Law of God vs Law of Christ](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/60657/law-of-god-vs-law-of-christ/60678#60678):

| John 7:16-17 |
| --- |
| <sup>16</sup>Jesus answered them and said, "**My doctrine is not Mine, but His who sent Me**. <sup>17</sup>If anyone wills to do His will, he shall know concerning the doctrine, **whether it is from God or whether I speak on My own authority**. <sub>(*Holy Bible: New King James Version.* Nashville, Tennessee: Thomas Nelson Publishers, 1982.)</sub> |

When it comes to biblical quotations, I personally like this format better than the standard ">" quotation formatting.

Should this become a new standard, or should it be discouraged, or what?

Comment: To be honest, I don't particularly like it. I'd say neither encouraged nor discouraged.

Comment: I like it, but I don't have any strong feelings either. It's hard enough getting new users to understand the site guidelines around scope, expected behaviour etc. I don't think its worth the effort of encouraging or discouraging any particular formatting for questions. If people like it enough then they'll probably adopt it themselves.

Comment: I agree with both the Moderators above. The usual format is simple and easy to use. I have just looked at the other and it is far too complicated to expect new users (some of whom are not - like myself - overly computer literate) to master and use it instantly.

Comment: While it may be pleasing to the eye, it does cause problems for the visually impaired that use a screen reader. The formatting tags for the formatting you give as an example would tell the visually impaired that this is a "table" whereas using the ">" would identify a blockquote. This is something that has been weighing on my mind as of late and would like a more definitive answer or guideline.

Comment: It wouldn't be a trouble if just the text speech calls the quote table in the beginning but if there are more issues like problem in the flow of the reader then it's very inconvenient for them. @agarza

Comment: The Bible reference should come at the beginning not end, I think this is convenient for everyone especially the blind.

Comment: The problem with tables is that the visually impaired user has to navigate the table manually whereas a blockquote will be read out naturally.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion for formatting:

> **[Romans 8:1-2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans+8%3A1-2&version=NIV)** (NIV)
>
> 8 Therefore, there is now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus, <sup>**2**</sup> because
> through Christ Jesus the law of the Spirit who gives life has set you free from the law of sin and death.

And this is how the formatting is input into the question/answer text field:

```
> **[Romans 8:1-2](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=romans+8%3A1-2&version=NIV)** (NIV)
>  
> 8 Therefore, there is now no condemnation for those who are in Christ Jesus, <sup>**2**</sup> because 
through Christ Jesus the law of the Spirit who gives life has set you free from the law of sin and death.
```

While the table format does look better, it's **not** conducive to a good "reading" experience for the visually impaired using a screen reader (this is known as [accessibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accessibility)). The screen reader will say that it is a table instead of identifying it as a blockquote; not to mention that navigating the table could confuse the visually impaired user.

Having the scripture, and a link to an online source, at the beginning of the blockquote helps the visually impaired to understand what is being quoted. If the quotation starts at the beginning of a chapter, having the chapter number at the beginning help identify it. If the quotation has multiple verses, the verse numbers marked as bold, superscript helps to distinguish them. If in the process of copying/pasting cross reference marks such as "[a]" are included, it would help the visually impaired to edit these out since no cross reference scripture is included.

Using this formatting will be easy to implement for new users and is accessible to the visually impaired.

I have come to this formatting after reviewing the information in the following links:

- [What formatting recommendations do you have for posts?](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359/what-formatting-recommendations-do-you-have-for-posts) by [Kazark](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/273/kazark)
- [Export BibleGatway page content in markdown format](https://stackapps.com/questions/2992/export-biblegatway-page-content-in-markdown-format) by [Caleb](https://stackapps.com/users/3583/caleb)
- [biblegateway-markdownifier](https://github.com/scottTomaszewski/biblegateway-markdownifier) by [Scott Tomaszewski](https://stackapps.com/users/33009/scott-tomaszewski)

Comment: You should simply mention theword.net PC app, as well as www.mybible.zone for phone, these bible apps include the quotation formats where we can save presets for this, and no need to go to biblegateway and to install any script. These free apps should be the standard ones for all.

Comment: Oh, I do not suggest using Bible Gateway or installing a script; that is just where I got the formatting. As I mentioned, this formatting is easiest for new users.